# Deserialize LocalDate from float/double

Tags: java, json, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have date from JSON:

```
"date":1660729012.307132
```

I have my model:

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Dto {
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER_FLOAT)
    private LocalDateTime date;
}
```

I want get `LocalDateTime` from this float using default configuration(I don't want write my own deserializer). So I try to create `ObjectMapper` and get my dto:

```
 ObjectMapper mapper =  new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
 var dto = mapper.readValue(json, Dto.class);
```

But I have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Expected array or string.
```

Comment: *How* do *you* want to convert "1660729012.307132" to a `LocalDate`? What does that number *mean*?

Comment: You could store the value in a double and have a method that converts the double to a LocalDateTime when needed or use a custom deserializer - I don't think there are many other alternatives...

Comment: @Sweeper it is data from API. In the documentation it says that it is Timestamp.

Comment: Reading [the docs](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html) you can use a string (ISO Format), a timestamp (java timestamp, i.e. non decimal) or a formatter - I don't think any of these 3 options can parse your decimal number.

Comment: You could try to use the number before the dot (.) as epoch seconds. That would require a cast to `long`. That result can be use to create an `Instant.ofEpochSecond(long)` which can then be use to derive [`Temporal`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/Temporal.html)

Comment: @Arya, this data came from `@Controller` in the request? Are you using Spring Boot in your project?

Answer (score 0):

I change `LocalDateTime date` to private `Instant date` and all work fine